# When to set `add_special_tokens=False` in huggingface transformers tokenizer?

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize, huggingface-transformers

this is the default way of setting `tokenizer` in the Hugging Face "transformers" library:

```
from transformers import BertForSequenceClassification,BertTokenizer
tokenizer=BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('ProsusAI/finbert')
tokens=tokenizer.encode_plus(text,add_special_tokens=True, max_length=512, truncation=True, padding="max_length")
```

As far as I understand, setting `add_special_tokens=True` adds the special tokens like [CLS], [SEP], and padding tokens to the input sequences. This is useful for the model's correct interpretation of the input. However, I've come across code samples where people set it to `False`.

I'm wondering in which specific situations should I set add_special_tokens=True and when should I set it to False when using tokenizer.encode_plus()? Are there any scenarios where managing special tokens manually after chunking or other preprocessing steps would be beneficial?